# How can I use custom maps on Call of Duty: World at War?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war

I'm looking to buy Call of Duty: World at War, but I want to know: How can I use custom maps downloaded by other players? I saw a video (vanossgaming) playing these maps, I don't know if he bought them but they are really expensive.

Can someone walk me through the steps: where can I find these custom maps/mods and how do I install them in the game? It is difficult? Is it legal to do so?

Comment: Are you just asking about custom maps? Because there are a ton of custom maps you can just download and use for free. Also Nazi zombies isn't a mod, it's just a gamemode.

Comment: yes i am asking only for custom maps...if you search on youtube vanossgaming world at war you will see those maps...do you know a safe site??  (i am going to buy this game with friends and we want to know how before we buy it)

Comment: If you just google for World at War custom zombie maps you will find plenty of them. As long as the sites don't look shady they are probably safe. I've downloaded multiple myself already, always worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chances of getting banned are slim to none, as Activision doesn't host any official servers for World at War now. Playing locally with friends, or hosting your own server, should be fine. The game's multiplayer is full of hosts and servers, so it would seem Activision has no problems with it.

A quick Google search turned up this promising tutorial on getting started:

[How to install and play custom zombie maps + other tips.](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=113282307)

Comment: thanks you a lot...if you cound send me a link for downloading maps i would appreciate it (i am going to buy this game with friends and we want to know how before we buy it)

Comment: @AnXeL I would check out the website www.moddb.com for maps, but there might be various other sites that host maps and mods.

Comment: thanks you so much...if you find an other site plzz comment <3

Comment: @AnXeL would you mind marking this as answered? I can comment back with other sites if I find any later today.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible legally for free if you want to host the game. For it to be legal, you must purchase the DLCs or you can join the maps with your friends but they have to invite you (afaik). Searching for "Call of Duty World at War mods" on Google turned out a few mod sites, for example [this](http://www.moddb.com/games/call-of-duty-world-at-war/mods) one. Easy/hard is relative, but I think it is pretty easy to mod the game.

Comment: so...how about my other questions??? (if i am in custom games alone or with friends i don't think that i could get banned)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if custom zombie maps work with steam. But if you have to non-steam version it's fairly easy.

There are some dedicated sites like [ZomMods](http://zommods.com/) or [ZombieModding](http://www.zombiemodding.com/) which provide you with various custom maps and tutorials to install them.

Also make sure to check out [UGX-Mods](http://ugx-mods.com/forum/) for more fancy custom maps with nice scripts.

Most of the time you download an **executable file (.exe)** and all you have to do, is run that file and you're set up!

It definitely isn't illegal, because with CoD World at War, there is a folder and a menu item "Mods" installed with the game. **The game is made for mods!**

I personally use [Tunngle](http://tunngle.net/) to play custom maps online. This way you don't need an Activision online profile for Call of Duty. In the game, you choose LAN. Tunngle creates a *public LAN*, so the game thinks you're actually sitting next to 100 players but really, you're just connected to the *Call of Duty World at War*-Lobby in Tunngle via the Internet.

Comment: so...i bought it....i download a map (ex airport)...it is a folder and i put it into the folder 'mods'...i launch the game...i press mods...i launch this mod...it chance the screen...but when i go to select the map i can find this map...i go to nazi zombies but there is only a map 'nacht der untoten' ...i tryed from consol and i press map nazi_zombie_airport and then ender but nothing happents...help??

Comment: Well, actually selecting the map differs from mod to mod.
It's seldom the case, that you have to launch a custom map via console. Most of the time the mod adds custom menu items.
You were right, by switching to Nazi zombies. There usually is only one map, but it should display the mod name. Have you tried launching `Nacht der Untoten`? Also, have you tried any other mod? When using console, don't forget to use the command `devmap` as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9SCKJwDrtE) or try `/map` as shown [here](https://youtu.be/Q5XJ3DmYTvo?t=6m18s).